# PHP RegEx: matching a word or sentence inside a html <p> BUT NOT inside <div> <img> <a> tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to match and replace about 100 words inside an html document creating links for each word. For performance reasons, I think DOM manipulation will be slower than preg_replace.

The thing is I want to be able to match (and replace) just simple words (or sentences)

`INSIDE <p> tags BUT NOT inside any other tag <a> <div> nor <img>.`

I'm using this regex expression to match the word "sapien":

```
/(<p[^>]*>)(.*)(?!<a\s[^>]+>[^<\/a>]+)(?!=\"[\w]*)(\bsapien\b)(?![^<\/a>]+<\/a>)(?![^\w]*\")(.*)(<\/p>)/imU
```

Here is the text where I'm applying it:

```
<p>Cras cursus consequat nibh <a href="#">sapien</a>ac vehicula. Sed erat sapien, condimentum quis risus nec, viverra dignissim nisi. Cras sapien convallis, erat egestas tincidunt <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="sapien" >rutrum, massa enim sagittis ante, sed pellentesque lorem risus vitae enim. Curabitur hendrerit dolor facilisis <a href="sapien">sapien</a> dolor malesuada molestie.</p>
```

I'm getting the match in

```
<a href="#">sapien</a>
```

which is inside  tag.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using DOM is probably slower, but it does a correct job, regex doesn't, and I don't think performances are important for this kind of task (that must be done once and for all).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to do this replacement on the fly. That's why I'm concerned about performance. I didn't try don manipulation but I will try it just to check how it behaves.

Comment: You mean inside a `p` tag, but not in *any* tag that is a child of the `p` tag? What if there are nested `p` tags? `<p>Some <p>text</p> here, see sapien</p>`?

Answer (score 2):

Solution in just one step, with negative lookahead:

`preg_replace("#\b(sapien)\b(?![^<>]*(<\/a|<\/div|>))#i", "<a href='#'>\\1</a>", $input);`

Demo: http://ideone.com/Z74X0f

With non-fixed width lookaround pattern we can only use lookahead (lookbehind doesn't work in that way), so we check for the presence of closing tags after our string.

Current regexp works good on example text, but may have some issues with nested tags. For example, if before ending tag will be any other tag, like here `<div> sapien <img></div>` it will also apply the replacement to that piece.

You can avoid this by adding extra variations to regexp:

`\b(sapien)\b(?!([^<>]*(<img[^>]+>)[^<>]*|[^<>]*)(<\/a|<\/div|>))`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/a5JiOo/2

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to split the logic, first find all parts/pieces that are not affected by tags `<a>`, `<div>` nor `<img>` and then replace your words/sentences in it.

I wrote php function `parse_text()` that sequentially scans the text and invoke callback function `my_replace()` every time when it had parsed new clean piece of text for replacement.

Working **demo** at: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HXPgEQ) and full listing above, I hope that solution will help you.

```
<?php
$input = <<<EOD
<p>sapien Cras cursus consequat nibh <a href="#">sapien</a>ac vehicula. Sed erat sapien, condimentum quis risus nec, viverra dignissim nisi. Cras sapien convallis, erat egestas tincidunt <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="sapien" >rutrum, massa enim sagittis ante, sapien.sed pellentesque lorem risus vitae enim. Curabitur hendrerit dolor facilisis <a href="sapien">sapien</a> dolor malesuada molestie.sapien</p>
EOD;

// define tags which you need to exclude from replacement 
// as: array( start_string => end_string, ... );
$ignore_tags = array(
    '<a' => '</a>',
    '<img' => '>',
    '<div' => '</div>'
);

echo "Input:\n {$input} \n\n ";
$output = parse_text($input, $ignore_tags);
echo "Output:\n {$output}";

// callback function that invokes every time when 'parse_text' parses 'clean' peace of text
function my_replace($text) {
    echo "my_replace call on: \n".$text."\n\n";

    // your replacements here
    $text = preg_replace("#\b(sapien)\b#i", "<a href=#>\\1</a>", $text);
    return $text;
}


// main parsing function that split text to clean and ignored parts
function parse_text($input, $ignore_tags) {
    $output = '';
    $str = '';
    $ignore = false;
    $current_ignore_tag = '';
    $ignore_tags_regexp = implode("|", array_keys($ignore_tags));

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        $str .= $input[$i];
        // if starts ignore tag and not already $ignore
        if (preg_match("#({$ignore_tags_regexp})$#si", $str, $m) && !$ignore) {
            $str = preg_replace("#({$ignore_tags_regexp})$#si", "", $str); // cut and not include ignore tag
            $output .= my_replace($str) . $m[1]; // replace all before and save
            $ignore = true;
            $current_ignore_tag = $m[1];
            $str = '';
        } // if $ignore and matches the end of the current ignore tag
        elseif ($ignore && preg_match("#({$ignore_tags[$current_ignore_tag]})$#i", $str, $m)) {
            $output .= $str; // just save as it is current peace
            $ignore = false;
            $str = '';
        }
    }
    $output .= (!$ignore) ? my_replace($str) : $str;
    return $output;
}
```

Result:

```
Input:
 <p>sapien Cras cursus consequat nibh <a href="#">sapien</a>ac vehicula. Sed erat sapien, condimentum quis risus nec, viverra dignissim nisi. Cras sapien convallis, erat egestas tincidunt <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="sapien" >rutrum, massa enim sagittis ante, sapien.sed pellentesque lorem risus vitae enim. Curabitur hendrerit dolor facilisis <a href="sapien">sapien</a> dolor malesuada molestie.sapien</p> 

 my_replace call on: 
<p>sapien Cras cursus consequat nibh 

my_replace call on: 
ac vehicula. Sed erat sapien, condimentum quis risus nec, viverra dignissim nisi. Cras sapien convallis, erat egestas tincidunt 

my_replace call on: 
rutrum, massa enim sagittis ante, sapien.sed pellentesque lorem risus vitae enim. Curabitur hendrerit dolor facilisis 

my_replace call on: 
 dolor malesuada molestie.sapien</p>

Output:
 <p><a href=#>sapien</a> Cras cursus consequat nibh <a href="#">sapien</a>ac vehicula. Sed erat <a href=#>sapien</a>, condimentum quis risus nec, viverra dignissim nisi. Cras <a href=#>sapien</a> convallis, erat egestas tincidunt <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="sapien" >rutrum, massa enim sagittis ante, <a href=#>sapien</a>.sed pellentesque lorem risus vitae enim. Curabitur hendrerit dolor facilisis <a href="sapien">sapien</a> dolor malesuada molestie.<a href=#>sapien</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy. It works although the performance is the big issue. It takes around 9 seconds to replace 140 words. Wondering if we can use negative lookahead to make this work in just one step (preg_replace)...

Comment: I've posted another solution with just one step using preg_replace, try it, and please share the results of the performance tests.